# Asking SAS to compute calculations based on dates

Tags: sas, data-manipulation

Lets say I have data regarding when an employee started working in a certain company.

11/3/1987
8/1/1990
8/3/1997
9/6/2004

I want to create a new variable saying yearsworked = (value here), which would give me the total number of years the employee has worked till the current date which is today. I know there is a Year() function but that just returns the date.

Comment: Please post what your data looks like, variables/values as well as what you expect the output to look like, and what you've tried.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the today() function... 
Assuming the variables StartDate is the years in your question, the following code will give you the years worked up to two decimal points. You can adjust the format to what you want.

```
data result;
    set your_table;
    format Years_worked 5.2;
    Years_worked = (today() - StartDate)/365.25;
run;
```

Comment: You might find the YRDIF function interesting.  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/67960/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1pmmr2dtec32an1vbsqmm3abil5.htm

Comment: @data_null_ You should post that as an answer.  I downvoted this answer as using `/365.25` is not good enough if you need the result to be correct all the time.  SAS provides plenty of functions for dealing with dates correctly, you should use those instead of loose calculations like that.

Comment: Robert, in which instances would 365.25 be incorrect?